# Has anyone got NFC Passkit certificates?

Tags: nfc, applepay, passkit, wallet

When you enable the `nfc` dictionary in the pass what does that pass do? It emulates an MIFARE card or simply extends Apple Pay with some extra data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it certainly is possible to get an NFC certificate.  However, the details of the implementation are protected by an NDA.  There is a link where you can apply for a certificate [here](https://developer.apple.com/contact/passkit/)